# Labels are overlapping in Syncfusion's flutter Doughnut chart

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

I have a categorization doughnut chart, where I display labels for each category fraction. The problem is that the labels are overlapping each other if the portion on the chart is very small.

If I set `labelIntersectAction: LabelIntersectAction.hide,`, most of the labels are not visible *(See in the 2nd screenshot)*, which left the user wondering about the categorization.

Here is my code:

```
     DoughnutSeries<ExpenseCategoryChartData, String>(
        dataSource: _chartData,
        radius: '65%',
        innerRadius: '75%',
        opacity: 0.5,
        pointColorMapper: (ExpenseCategoryChartData data, _) =>
            data.bgColor,
        xValueMapper: (ExpenseCategoryChartData data, _) => '${data.x}',
        yValueMapper: (ExpenseCategoryChartData data, _) => data.y,
        enableSmartLabels: true,
        enableTooltip: true,
        sortingOrder: SortingOrder.ascending,
        dataLabelMapper: (data, __) => '${data.x}',
        dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(
          // Renders the data label
          isVisible: true,
          labelIntersectAction: LabelIntersectAction.none,
          labelAlignment: ChartDataLabelAlignment.top,
          connectorLineSettings: ConnectorLineSettings(
            length: '10',
            type: ConnectorType.curve,
            width: 2,
          ),
          labelPosition: ChartDataLabelPosition.outside,
        ),
      ),
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

While setting `labelIntersectAction` value as `hide`, the labels which are overlapped each other will be hidden and also the labels which exceeds the chart area bounds will also be hidden.

[Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcobM.png)

So for your scenario to show the label which exceeds the bounds, either you can set the margin property value as 0 (for example margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0)) or else you has to reduce the radius of the chart.

Please refer the below code snippet below.

```
return Container(
margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
child: SfCircularChart(
  series: <CircularSeries>[
    DoughnutSeries<ChartData, String>(
      dataSource: chartData,
      radius: '50%',
      innerRadius: '75%',
      opacity: 0.5,
      pointColorMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.color,
      xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => '${data.x}',
      yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y,
      enableSmartLabels: true,
      enableTooltip: true,
      sortingOrder: SortingOrder.ascending,
      dataLabelMapper: (data, __) => '${data.x}',
      dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(
        isVisible: true,
        labelIntersectAction: LabelIntersectAction.hide,
        labelAlignment: ChartDataLabelAlignment.top,
        connectorLineSettings: ConnectorLineSettings(
          length: '10',
          type: ConnectorType.curve,
          width: 2,
        ),
        labelPosition: ChartDataLabelPosition.outside,
      ),
    ),
  ],
 ),
);
```

[Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNMKT.png)

Comment: I removed some margins, it did fix things for my screen, but it is not a solution I was looking for.